# Chow's theorem for time one flows

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, markov-chains, stochastic-differential-equations

Chow's theorem gives a criterion for the reachable set of the points of a manifold $M$ to be full. Specifically, if we have a distribution $D$ whose iterated commutators span the tangent bundle then any point $p$ can be reached by any point $q$ by some composition of the flows of the vectors fields from $D$.

If we fix the time that each flow can be followed, is there an analogous criterion? For example, if we restrict the time we can follow each flow to time $1$. If we can't reach each point, are we able to reach each open set $U$?

There is obviously no direct analog since following time $1$ maps of the vectors fields $[1/5, 0]$, and $[0, 1/5]$ on $\mathbb{T}^2$ give a finite collection of points when you start at $(0, 0)$.

My intuition says to look at ergodicity for density of trajectories, but this has not given any results.

Does anyone have any references or known theorems I should look at?